# classList add/remove function

Tags: javascript

Надо `classList.add/remove` закинуть в функцию.
Почему не работает?

```
function cL(elem, addOrRemove, className) {
  return elem.classList.addOrRemove(className);
}

var div = document.querySelector('div');
cL(div, add, 'red');
```

Comment: какой результат вы получаете?

Comment: [classList.toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Comment: div получает класс .red {bgcolor:red;}

Comment: окей, попытался заюзать скобочную нотацию, не работает:)

Comment: Не нужно править код вопроса после его постинга - вы можете исправить его и вопрос потеряет смысл. Что Вы и сделали, хотя не все ошибки исправили.

Comment: @Aid ты кажется не туда откатил

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, я все поправил :-)

Comment: по-моему если люди видят слово "дубликат", то врятли отрывают вопрос. а  вопрос так и не решился, кстати)

Comment: @urpride, если стоит слово дубликат, то люди и не должны открывать вопрос, это автор вопрос должен открыть дубликат и посмотреть о чем он. Из того, что ты редактировал, один из вариантов был правильным, надо просто иметь ввиду, что передавать надо строку, а ты передаешь какую-то переменную `add`, которая возможно нигде не объявлена и у тебя на самом деле куча ошибок в консоли

Comment: решено, спасибо

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, да, глюканул..